# SublimeText: How do I use regex to find dynamic content in a string?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm currently cleaning up an XML file manually and removing unnecessary content and tags. It would help hugely if I could find all instances of a tag with its dynamic content and remove it with SublimeText Regex. How do I do this?
This is the tag that needs to be found. The content within the quotes is dynamic, which means I can't do simple find replace:

```
[simple_tooltip content='Colour Printer']
```

Is there a regex syntax that can help me kill the content within the quotes?
I've Googled a bit and haven't been able to find a clear way of doing this. However, regex is also confusing... Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Sublime so this may be a little off, but I think you're looking for something like this?

**Find** `content='.+?'` **Replace** `content=''`

**Explanation**

1. Match `content='` literally
2. Match `.` (any character) `+` (1 or more times) `?` (lazily)
3. Match `'` literally

Comment: WOW. You literally made my day. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :D